# If Home Page Do Nothing, If All Else Show This Content

Tags: options

I have this code:

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_page() || is_archive() || is_404() || is_tag()) { ?>

<div class="single-page-title">
<div class="spt-wrap grid-container container grid-parent">
<div class="spt-title">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php } elseif (is_home() || is_front_page()) { ?><?php } ?>
```

I would like it to only show the HTML content on all other pages/posts/archives other than the home page itself. I do not want it to show on the homepage.

Can someone rewrite this for me?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for:

```
if ( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
{
   // the stuff you don't want to show on the front/home page
}
```

where we use that `! ( A || B ) = ! A && ! B`.

But it also depends where in the theme you are using the code snippet.

Comment: Thank you. I did cast a vote but I am a newbie on here.

Comment: You're welcome. Users need some amount of points to vote but one can always accept answers to ones questions, Welcome to the site. @RichardBland